# Why I can't do "shift subroutine_name()" in Perl?

Tags: perl

Why does this code return an `Not an ARRAY reference` error?

```
sub Prog {
    my $var1 = 1;
    my $var2 = 2;
    ($var1, $var2);
}

my $variable = shift &Prog;
print "$variable\n";
```

If I use an intermediate array, I avoid the error:

```
my @intermediate_array = &Prog;
my $variable = shift @intermediate_array;
print "$variable\n";
```

The above code now outputs "1".

Comment: What's with the `&`?  And what's wrong with `my ($variable) = Prog;`?

Comment: Nothing is "wrong" with that construct, @cHao, but OP clearly doesn't know about it.  OP probably also is learning from an old tutorial that shows `&` for function calls.

Comment: @AndyLester: Wow, those tutorials still exist?  `&function` has been outdated style for at least a decade.  Seems step 1 would be to find a less ancient resource to learn from.

Comment: Something somewhere he read said to call subs with ampersand, right?  He didn't make it up on his own.  So he must be working with an old tutorial or an old book or something.

Comment: I know that it's sometimes possible to omit `&` in function calls. But for me it's easier to always use `&` then to remember additional rules when I can omit it and when can't.

Comment: @Alexander: There are very, very few places where the `&` sigil is even useful anymore, let alone required.  The only one that comes to mind is calling a code reference, but even then you can say `$function->()` IIRC (which is almost always less funky).

Comment: @cHao "Wow, those tutorials still exist?" Unfortunately, yes. Based on the number of questions we get on Stack Overflow with Perl code that looks like it was written in 1994, they aren't that hard to find either.

Comment: @Alexander: *Please* drop the use of `&` on subroutine calls, as it will cause you problems. Firstly, it overrides any subroutine prototypes (which isn't such a problem as you shouldn't be using prototypes anyway) but when you specify no parameters it also passes the current contents of `@_` as the parameter list, which can be a game breaker. So in your example, you are *actually* writing `my @intermediate_array = Prog(@_)`. You need to use `&` only when referring to subroutines as first-class data, usually when taking a reference, as in `my $subref = \&Prog`.

Comment: Re "I know that it's sometimes possible to omit & in function calls." It should *always* be omitted.

Comment: @Alexander: If you call a function with arguments like `Prog(arg1, arg2)` then you never need the `&`.  If there are no arguments, just use empty parentheses `Prog()`. You can omit the parentheses if your function definition precedes the function call.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The subroutine `Prog` returns a list of scalars.  The `shift` function only operates on an array.  Arrays and lists are not the same thing.  Arrays have storage, but lists do not.

If what you want is to get the first element of the list that `Prog` returns, do this:

```
sub Prog {
    return ( 'this', 'that' );
}

my $var = (Prog())[0];
print "$var\n";
```

I changed the sub invocation to `Prog()` instead of `&Prog` because the latter is decidedly old style.

You can also assign the first element to a scalar like others are showing:

```
my ($var) = Prog();
```

This is roughly the same as:

```
my ($var, $ignored_var) = Prog();
```

and then ignoring `$ignored_var`.  If you want to make it clear that you're ignoring the second value without actually giving it a variable, you can do this:

```
my ($var, undef) = Prog();
```

Comment: Note that `shift` in new versions of Perl will (experimentally) accept an array references, so `shift Prog()` (being short for `shift @{ Prog() }`) should work for `sub Prog { [ 4,5 ] }`.

Answer (score 7):

`Prog` is returning a **list**, not an **array**. Operations like `shift` modify the array and cannot be used on lists.

You can instead do:

```
my ($variable) = Prog; # $variable is now 1: 
                       # Prog is evaluated in list context 
                       # and the results assigned to the list ($variable)
```

Note that you don't need the `&`.